# Distinguish between 'editable' and 'non-editable' windows forms controls

Tags: c#, winforms

In Windows Forms, is there a way to distinguish between the controls that are 'editable' like TextBox, DateTimePicker, ComboBox etc. and 'non-editable' controls like Panel, Form, TabPage etc.?

I'm writing a function that recursively enables or disables controls on a form, but only want to 'touch' controls that actually take user input. I was hoping that there was a smart way to distinguish.

Thank you.

Comment: Even controls, which by default are non-touchable, like a Label or a Penel can be hooked up to, say Mouse events, so the whole distinction makes not much sense imo. Why not en/disable them all?

Comment: Maybe I should be more clear. I don't want to disable panels or tabpages etc. because they can contain controls of the other types. If you disable a panel, the child controls inherit the setting, which is not desired.

Comment: Then make a list of the types you want to disable..

Comment: That is effectively what I've done so far. It seemed a little verbose and it felt strange 'hard coding' so many types, hence the question; I was hoping to be more 'clever' about it. Thank you for your responses.

Comment: Yeah, I have looked into reflection but the properties and event usually are declared in the control class. Maybe the list of exceptions is shorter? - ;-)